# RVM doesn't seem to play well with ruby-1.9.3-preview1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler

I installed the ruby-1.9.3-preview1 after updating my rvm by following the steps below:

```
 » rvm get head
 » rvm reload
 » rvm install ruby-1.9.3-preview1
```

Then I create a gem set for my project and try to use it.

```
 » rvm --create ruby-1.9.3@myproject
 » rvm use ruby-1.9.3@myproject
```

I test it out by:

```
 » ruby -v                         
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-07-31 revision 32789) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]
```

But then when I try using it:

```
 » bundle exec rails server
/Users/<home>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@envision/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
```

it still seems to be using the older version of Ruby. Did anyone else face this issue or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I originally intended to install the latest ruby-1.9.3-rc1. I switched to using that, by following the same steps above, and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue, which seems completely unrelated to rvm or ruby-1.9.3. There was a problem with my bundler config. I hope this helps anyone who is surprised by seeing there gem sets not being used.

So,

```
 » bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.

path
  Set for the current user (/Users/<home>/.bundle/config): "/Users/<home>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myproject"

….
```

which meant it would always use the gem set under the path by default.

```
 » bundle config path ''
```

seems to fix the issue. I am sure there a better way to remove any config overrides on the bundle config default by an explicit remove. But so far this worked and I have my new gem set with 1-.9.3-rc1 being used. Unfortunately not all my gems are compiling with 1.9.3-rc1, specifically an issue with gherkin-2.2.9. Let me know if someone got it work. I guess this a different question.

**EDIT**

```
 » bundle config path ''
```

Doing that is a bad idea. I realized my mistake soon as this will default the current directly for creating your gemset.

```
 » bundle config path $GEM_HOME
```

The above is better, after making sure GEM_HOME points to …/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@myproject . So yes I would still like to know how to let bundle config use the defaults so I don't have to change it myself. I tried editing .bundle/config with no luck under the `myproject` directory.